# how to get the level of a path in matplotlib contour

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working on [contourf](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html) to get the contours of some gridded data.
But I do not understand how to get the correspondent level of every path (neither do I know for polygons) returned by contourf.

Needless to say this information is present, since when [plotted](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/contour-plot-using-matplotlib-python/) different levels correspond to different colours.

Trivial code example:

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot

grid = numpy.empty((5,5))

grid[:2] = 0
grid[2:] = 2

print(grid)

contour_set = pyplot.contourf(range(5), range(5), grid, levels=[1,2]) 
#at least two levels are needed so i give a random one

polygon = contour_set.collections[0].get_paths()[0].to_polygons()[0]

print(polygon)
```

Here the path is clearly of level '2' but the issue comes when there are many different levels.

Comment: You could try to call contourf multiple times, once for each of the level pairs.

Comment: Thought about it, but if I have shapes with internal voids (and unfortunately I have them) then I get some polygons around those voids. And I can't distinguish between these two types of polygons (unless i manually check every pair to know if one contains the other, but it is rather uncomfortable)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC the `contour_set.levels` array contains the information you are after. Disregard the first element, since that doesn't correspond to any polygon (level 1 in your case):

```
for level, collection in zip(contour_set.levels[1:], contour_set.collections):
    print(f"%% Level {level} %%")
    print(collection.get_paths()[0].to_polygons())
```

"... correspondent level of every path ... " => Note that the levels correspond to a collection, not to a path (think two peaks, where a given collection might include two circles (paths), corresponding to the same level)

Comment: It's still not clear to me. You said 'disregard the first element'. But in a real scenario I would have linked the first collection to level 1 not level 2. I do not know in advance that there are no paths for level 1. If what you said is true shouldn't contour_set.collections contain one empty collection and then the one for level 2?

Comment: Well, in your example `contour_set.collections` does contain a single PathCollection object only, while `contour_set.levels` contains 2 values (1 and 2). This makes sense if you think of the contours as "boundaries between levels" rather than "the levels".

Comment: Then it's a matter of convention whether you assign each contour to the next level, or the previous level, i.e. `zip(contour_set.levels[1:], contour_set.collections)` vs `zip(contour_set.levels[:-1], contour_set.collections)`

Comment: I thought every path (or polygon) returned was a figure containing a specific level (therefore associated with that level). Instead it's more like boundaries between consecutive levels?